# class variables v/s instance variables in python

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

from my past knowledge of python oop i know that python has a single copy of a class variable for all class instances;it means:

```
>>> class A: foo = []
>>> a, b = A(), A()
>>> a.foo.append(5)
>>> b.foo
[5]
```

but when i do this:

```
>>> class A():
    cl_var=5
    def __init__(self,b):
        self.obj_var=b


>>> a1,a2=A(2),A(5)
>>> a1.cl_var
5
>>> a1.cl_var=23
>>> a2.cl_var
5
```

why a2.cl_var not changing to 23 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign to `a1.cl_var` you *rebind* `cl_var` associated with `a1`. This does not affect `a2.cl_var`.

```
>>> id(a1.cl_var), id(a2.cl_var)
(11395416, 11395416)
```

As you can see, `a1.cl_var` and `a2.cl_var` are the same object.

However, when you assign to `a1.cl_var`, they become different objects:

```
>>> a1.cl_var=23
>>> id(a1.cl_var), id(a2.cl_var)
(11395200, 11395416)
```

This does not happen in the `a`/`b` example because there you *modify* `foo` via a reference. You don't rebind (i.e. assign to) it.